# lua-cjson decode error when parse nested object

Tags: lua

> s = cjson.decode(s)

I want to decode the statement like this, but got `Expected value but found invalid token at character 27` error. I tried another statement like below:

> {"status_code":503,"body":"{"code": 1, "message": "Service unavailable"}"}
>
> {"status_code":503,"body":{"code": 1, "message": "Service unavailable"}}

However there is same error. It looks like cjson does't support decode nested? Is there another solution? Thx.

Comment: The first example, `{"status_code":503,"body":"{"code": 1, "message": "Service unavailable"}"}`, has too many quotation marks. The second example `{"status_code":503,"body":{"code": 1, "message": "Service unavailable"}}` is correct and my cjson can decode it.

Comment: @cyclaminist Thx's a lot. I got a solution.The reason is the `body` was treated as string and  handled by `cjson.encode`. So the `"` was translated to `\"`.

Answer (score 0):

JSON data like this is easy to convert to Lua code:

```
s=[[
{"status_code":503,"body":{"code": 1, "message": "Service unavailable"}}
]]

s=s:gsub('(".-"):','[%1]=')
t=load("return "..s)()
for k,v in pairs(t) do print(k,v) end
for k,v in pairs(t.body) do print(k,v) end
```