# How to split a string with multiple elements and sub-element into table in Lua

Tags: lua

I am writing a test function that can parse a string into tables. Here is the test string:

```
{"part A": [{"id":2264,"name":"My Tank","uniqueId":"014682003358115"}],"Part B" :[{"id":32,"attributes":{"adc":"0","raw":"0","cid":"89302750000000044889","distance":6277.98,"land":"SE-8-45-3-W2","ip":"193.181.246.215"},"deviceId":2264,
"portName":"demo test ca","portNumber":1}]}
```

What i want as result is something like this:

```
Part A: 

   id:2264

   name: "My tank"

....etc

Part B:

   id: 32

   attribute: (here is a sub table where element is belong to attribute)

      adc: 0

.....etc
```

I looked for split join in lua document but it doesnt answer as how to put the table and sub table.

I am thinking of something simple like this:

```
function ParseString(s, delimiter)
    local result = {}
    for match in (s..delimiter):gmatch("(.-)"..delimiter) do
        table.insert(result, match)

    end

    return result

end
```

but it wont work for multiple delimeter like in this string

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42140295/107090 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51662463/107090

Comment: I would use a well-tested JSON module, such as https://luarocks.org/modules/dhkolf/dkjson